# Django migrations not getting applied on Postgres after changing the datatype of an attribute in models.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I had this model where the `price` was an Integer Field. I did run migrations and all was fine.

```
from django.db import models

class Bill(models.Model):
    price= models.IntegerField()
```

Then due to requirement changes, I had to make the `price` field as JSONField which would store the `price` value based on certain keys similar to this

```
price={"actual_price":100, "tax_price":20}
```

I made the changes in the model like below:

```
from django.db import models

class Bill(models.Model):
    price= JSONField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I performed makemigrations and migrate operations, the migrations are not getting reflected in DB. There are no errors as well. I get the error "Column: price does not exist" when my code tries to read from the DB.

I tried the following things by referring to StackOverflow other questions:

1. Removed the field. Run migrations, applied it. Removing field works
   fine. But when I add the field back instead of considering it as new
   field to be added, it just doesn't get inserted.
2. Removing the migrations from the migrations.py folder, re-running it and re-applying it.

Please note:

1. I am using Postgres DB. The same thing works for SQLite DB which is in-house provided by Django but not for Postgres.
2. Losing the data is not a feasible option as the DB data is of production server.
3. I tried adding the column **manually** through PostGres using the query ALTER Table ADD Column which worked perfectly fine. This is a hook that I used which was used as a last resort.
4. The data in the initial integer field was present for some of the records before applying the updated migration. Strange thing is I also wasn't asked by Django to set the value in case I want to override the data.

I need the Django migrations for applying the changes automatically to work. Due to this issue, only the addition of new column and modifying the datatype of the column is not working at all (Rest operations like removing the column works).

Comment: Where is this JSONField from? Can you show how you import it?

Comment: Can you show the migration generated? Also is the data in the current integer field data that need to persist? That was not clear

Comment: @heyhugo We verified the migration generated. The migration was updated with latest changes. Unfortunately I wont be able to attach the migration file as its against the policy of company. But we can say that the migrations had the latest changes. And the data in the current integer field was present for some of the records. Strange thing is I also wasnt asked by django to set the value incase I want to override the data. Updated the question, thanks for pointing this.

Comment: Ok I see but can you inspect the migrations and see what operations are in there and in what order, e.g. `AlterField`, `RemoveField` `AddField` maybe there's some clue there.

Also check with `python manage.py showmigrations` the state of you your migrations are all run or did any of them fail?

Comment: @heyhugo While following  one of the solutions from SO, I had removed the migrations from the folder and then re-run the migrations in the hopes of getting it running. But that too failed. So, now there is no way for me to check in what order it was applied.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The JSONField is sent from UI via http post method to django backend for saving.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Where is the code? Are you using a third-party library, or is it from django.contrib.postgres? Exactly how did you import it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman No its not from django.contrib.postgres. We used  "from jsonfield import JSONField"  which is from django-jsonfield.

Comment: But the note on that repo says not to use it for new projects. Why aren't you using the contrib.postgres one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman We are using SQLite for non prod server and PostGres for Prod Server. Thats why we used django provided type. And we had used JSONField before too, the migrations were working fine then. But when I changed the type of the existing variable and then did migrations everything got screwed up totally..Now no new migrations work even though I have made the changes to PostGres DB manually and fixed it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there was no other option and no solutions provided, I had to point my application to new DB in PostGres and then it started working fine. Lesson Learnt for future:

1. Not to update directly the datatype of the model attribute and then apply migrations.
2. First Remove the field, apply migrations and then create the field with same name and required data type and then apply migrations.
3. Use the same Database that you are using for production in your local itself. In this way, you can avoid conflicts after deploying to production. I had used SQLite for local and PostGres for Production. From now on, I will use PostGres for Local also so that I can debug issues in my local itself.